# Why is this WinMobile (Compact Framework) app hanging after photo taken?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, freeze, windows-mobile-6.5

I am having a very difficult time trying to debug/fix an application.

Briefly:
- I created a "wizard" type app that starts with the user taking a photograph (using the common dialog for photos)

- If the user tries to use the text input window (SIP) (the little keyboard input window) after a photo is taken the event loop seems to hang - the event is not processed or is delayed for a while.
- If the user does not take a picture the SIP keyboard works great.
- This only happens on some of my devices.  Specifically it is not a problem on an MC65 but is a problem on an ES400.

It appears that the app's event loop gets screwed up with the way I am displaying forms and taking photos.

If created a simple test app with single form containing a button (Event handler takes a photo) and a text box that accepts input.  That works fine.  But it is only a single form app that does nothing else.

When I combine the photo taking with my form displaying (making a "wizard" ) things go badly.

I wonder what kind of event loop should I be running?

Essentially the user takes a photo then goes through some forms (I hide one form and show another when they click the "next" button.)

The Form.Show is called from the main form after a picture is taken and then I have something like:

```
while(UserNotFinished)
{
   Application.DoEvents()
}
```

Where `UserNotFinished` is a flag set from my wizard/forms after the "submit" button is pressed.

I will be happy to provide more code but not sure what would be useful.

I am new to C# and CF development (lots of years of C++/Win32)

The real confusing part is that this works on one device but not on another.  In fact, the device hangs completely.  It ends the activesync connection and sometimes I have to hard reset by removing the battery.

Comment: If you've been using Win32 for year, how would you have achieved the effect you're trying to get with the DoEvent loop?  Would you have called `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` in a loop (that's what you're doing here)?  My guess is that you wouldn't.  Try looking at it from the angle of your Win32 experience.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I had copied some (bad) code form the internets...  my first mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the while(true) { DoEvents(); } and perhaps how you are trying to go between forms.  The only time I've used the DoEvents() method is when I'm already in the scope of a windows event and I need to be sure something in the message queue is processed so screen updates are correct.  I'd suggest making a controller class to manage the screen flow for your wizard.  You can control the screen flow by either using ShowDialog() and execute the flow control directly in the scope of a single call, or you'll have to use Show() and an asynchronous mechanism such as subscribing to and handling specific form and control events in the controller class. Also saw the comment about introducing another thread, beware that Forms belong to the thread they were created in and you must Invoke(...) all Form members in the context of the creating thread.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Very strange

I started a new thread and basically call Application.DoEvents() in in as well and it seems to fix the problem...

I don't know why the

while(true)
{
DoEvents() 
}

in the main thread doesn't work.

Comment: The DoEvents() in the main thread doesn't work, because it's your main thread that is hanging. Otherwise the application would be able to do the DoEvents() on it's own. I would take a look on your event handlers that could hang your main thread with something like processing a photo.

Comment: Oh, and as far as I know, calling DoEvents() is considered to be evil.

Comment: Yes, DoEvents() is bad. This is a leftover of bad programming practices from VB programmers. It basically says, "I don't know what to do or what I am doing."

Comment: I've maintained for years that `DoEvents` is not inherently evil or bad, it's just maligned by those who don't use it right.  It's simply the equivalent to a C `GetMessage`/`DispatchMessage` call, which is not problematic *if you know what it does and why you should use it*.  Just calling it for the sake of "I was trying to synchronize threads in my app" is where it leads to trouble.

Comment: The use of DoEvent() was copied from an example online - that probably was my first mistake.  I had to roll my own "wizard" UI for mobile.  I will try to re-architect without it.